# MSBuild - Remote Agent URL Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, teamcity, web-deployment, webdeploy

I have been using the "Publish Web" dialog in VS2010 for over a year. In the "Service URL" section I have:

http://server.workapps.com

...and my deploys work no problem for ALL my apps.

Now I am trying to create a CI environment using Teamcity and ran into the problem where by my stated property:

```
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl="http://server.workapps.com"
```

...started erroring.

To debug I started using command line MSBuild.exe until I got the correct settings but again here MSBuild is translating my property:

"/p:MsDeployServiceUrl="http://server.workapps.com"

...into a request that errors with:

```
"Remote agent (URL https://server.workapps.com:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=uat.workapps.com) could not be contacted.
```

FYI on the server Web Deploy is set to run on http:80 and I am trying to deploy a MVC Web Applciation (c#).

Can anyone tell me why it is not using the URL I gave and adding https and ports on?

Please see my parameters below:

```
/p:Configuration=Debug
/p:DeployOnBuild=True
/p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl="http://server.workapps.com" 
/p:username=Administrator 
/p:password=NotOriginalPassword
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True 
/P:CreatePackageOnPublish=True 
/p:DeployIisAppPath=uat.workapps.com 
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC
```

Thanks Paul

Comment: As soon as you posted your password among other params and it still can be found in revisions of this question - I strongly recommend you to change it ASAP. For the safety of your server.

Comment: thanks, but it is all fake URLs and passwords.

Comment: Oh, sorry then, it looks so real to me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear I need to use the following:

```
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent
```

as opposed to WMSVC.